# Cannot access hidden folder in flutter like .Statuses in Android 11?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, file-permissions

I tried solutions given for similar questions, which the solution is adding ManageExternalStorage permission to AndroidManifest.xml. But Playstore rejected my app to have permission which is sensitive like this.

But Other developers in GooglePlay manages to access  /.Statuses (hiddenfolder) without any sensitive permission. How do they able to achieve that without the solution given above??

Comment: `I tried solutions given for similar questions,` What questions?

Comment: @blackapps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70393591/cannot-access-hidden-folder-on-android-version-11-device-in-flutter